# Loop for checking multiple conditions in SAS with or without MACROS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am new to SAS and read [SAS if statement in do loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179237/sas-if-statement-in-do-loop) and I am still confused on how to solve the loop problem. I also have no idea to use Macro here.

The code is given belòow:

```
if DIA_PRINCd=001
or DIA_UNOd  =001
or DIA_DUEd  =001
or DIA_TREd  =001
or DIA_QUATTROd=001
or DIA_CINQUEd =001

or DIA_PRINCd=002
or DIA_UNOd  =002
or DIA_DUEd  =002
or DIA_TREd  =002
or DIA_QUATTROd=002
or DIA_CINQUEd=002
--------------------
---------------------
or DIA_PRINCd=142
or DIA_UNOd=142
or DIA_DUEd=142
or DIA_TREd=142
or DIA_QUATTROd=142
or DIA_CINQUEd=142
;
```

run;

May I know how to use loop in SAS for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the same set of variables are being tested for a variety of diagnostic codes, such as `001`, `002`, ..., `142` as criteria for a subsetting `if`.

The `or` operator means that if a single sub-clause is true the subset should occur.

You can create a variable array for the `DIA_*` and loop over the codes you want to test.  Within the loop the `WHICHN` function call tell you if *any* of the variables in the array matches a code.  If the diagnoses values are actually character type `"001"`, use `WHICHC`.

Example:

```
  array diagnoses dia_:;
  found = 0;
  do code = 001, 002, ..., 142;                 /* list of codes to check */
    found = whichn(code, of diagnoses(*));      /* check if present */  
    if found then leave;                        /* stop checking at earliest find */
  end;

  if found;    /* subsetting if.  At least one of the variables matched one of the codes */
```

The `WHICHN` and `WHICHC` functions implicitly loop over the values passed to it (i.e. the values from the variables in the `of array-name(*)`)

Comment: May I know how to add columns in existing dataset with name of those codes with value either 0 or 1...? many thanks for ur help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219061/sas-loop-create-columns-from-the-records-which-are-having-a-value

Comment: Thumbs up for creating new question.